# Random Variable Distribution Problem Help Needed

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains

Let $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ be random variables, each of which take values in {0, 1}

Let: $p(Y_1 = y_1)$=$\frac{y_1+1}{3}$

$p(Y_3 = y_3|Y_1 = y_1)$=$\frac{y_3+y_1+1}{2y_1+3}$

$p(Y_2 = y_2|Y_1 = y_1, Y_3 = y_3)$= $\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     \frac{(y_2+y_1+1)^2}{(y_1+1)^2+(y_1+2)^2}  &\mbox{for $y_3=0$}  \\
     \frac{y_2+1}{3} & \mbox{for $y_3=1$}
\end{array}\right.$

Use these distributions to find:

i) $p(Y_3 = 0|Y_1 = 1)$

ii) $p(Y_1 = 0|Y_3 = 1)$

I don't have any problems with i) as you sub $0$ and $1$ into the second distribution and get 2/5 as my answer. But ii) is confusing me so if someone could help me, that will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Use Bayes rule.

Comment: How would you apply it in this question, I cant seem to work out which distributions to use in ii) @SteveD

Answer (score 1):

To find $p(Y_1{=}y_1\mid Y_3{=}y_3)$, apply Bayes' Rule (using appropriate events $A,B$)

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B)= \dfrac{p(B\mid A)~p(A)}{p(B)}$$

And using the Law of Total Probability, $p(B)=p(B\mid A)~p(A)+p(B\mid\neg A)~p(\neg A)$ , may also be useful.

Comment: I see, so I assume you use the law of total probability to find $p(Y_3=y_3)$

Comment: Also is your notation for the second part of your law of total probability formula wrong????

Comment: No, it is quite okay.  $\neg A$ is the complement of event $A$, also written as $A^\complement$.  In this case, since the variables have only two values, of $0, 1$, this suffices.

Comment: so when using the law of total probability would you get: $p(Y_3=y_3)=p(Y_3 = y_3|Y_1 = 0)  p(Y_1=y_1)+p(Y_3 = y_3|1 = y_1) p(Y_1=y_1)$